# Artist profile information not getting from spotify api

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

Artist profile information not getting from api.

Im calling this URL

```
url=https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/****7vxl9s3awf7hz4rr
```

Endpoint(s):
**GET /v1/artists/{id}**

---

Scope(s):

### *Not required as per the dev doc.*

Steps to reproduce:

1. Authenticate user - get Oauth Token
2. Call GET /v1/me - get user info (id,display_name etc)
3. CAll GET /v1/artists/{id} - Get the artist information.

---

Expected behaviour:
Artist object as described on;
**https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-artist/?id= {id}**.

---

Actual behaviour:

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=400, message=, url=https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/****7vxl9s3awf7hz4rr*****}
```

Response Body

```
{"error":{"status":400,"message":"invalid id"}}
```

Questions - How to get artist information from spotify API?

Comment: What happens when you try an artist id on the page you linked to, have you added the **** yourself as those shouldn't be there, assuming an error in the question there but try the Id, 7vxl9s3awf7hz4rr, first there and see if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should do like this.

Step 1: Get the Display name from spotify using spotify SDK or GET ME API.

GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me

Step 2: Using that Display name search for the artist in Artist API.

GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/search

You will get the result of that artist.

Step 3: Compare the result what you get with the display name.(Because thier might be other artist also with matching one word of that user's display name).
You need to compare it in your code.

Step 4: When you get the result, it will give type as artist and also the artist Id.

Now you know that when a user login in your application, weather he has artist account or not.

Comment: Thanks @Salman Riyaz, After geting spotify id from search api am able to compare name against search result. using spotify api now i am hitting artist/spotify_id working fine.

Thanks man.

Comment: Great that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Small warning, As I do understand the approach by Salman Riyaz, it seems not to be a reliable approach to overcome something like issue #10 at Spotify, just if this matters for your use case

> [Retrieve connection between Artist and User profiles · Issue #10 ·
> spotify/web-api](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/10)
>
> [...working with the Spotify API and am wondering how I go about
> allowing an artist to login and see their own tracks. I was thinking
> that perhaps all Spotify accounts are linked to Artists once they get
> an artist profile created?...](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Spotify-for-artists-API/td-p/5067109)